# Android App without a Main Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

I would like for my application to not show any activity except on launch or specifically requested by the widget it contains. In other words I want it to find and launch the main activity on Launching the app, but otherwise I don't want any Activity at all to show unless an intent specifically requests it.  I don't want the app coming to the foreground to mean that the main activity always displays.  How can the main activity be supressed except on launch? thanks

Comment: This question is not understandable... please write some good explained scenarios so we can understand what you want

Comment: Ok. let me clarify.  When the user launches the application I want it to show a Main activity for user interaction.  But the rest of the time I have no need for the user to see any activity at all, until the user clicks on a widget link.

Comment: My widget is deployed as part of an application that has a service.  So its mostly about the widget <--> service communication. I really have no need for an Activity to display when the application/service is running.  Why does there need to be a visible Activity at all times?

Comment: There is no requirement for you to have any activity at all. What are you referring to?

Comment: ok there might not be a requirement, but when you launch the application from the application group then i do want it to show.  So what I am saying is that I don't want a main activity to be displayed when the application is starting up unless it is launched from application icon

Comment: when i took the main action out then android refused to load from icon and said application is not available.

Comment: here is the exact behavior I am trying to get.  Perhaps this will make it more clear.  When device boots auto launch the app but don't show a main activity.  Don't show any activity at all.  However if the user specifically launches the application from launch pad then I want an main activity to show.  In other words I want to be able to run the app without a main activity if it is auto launched but if the user launches it I want it to show.

Comment: The answer appears to be yes you can.  So I have posted another question on conditionally showing the main activity based on how the application is launched.

Comment: Related question is here if you want to comment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988774/android-can-applicaton-detect-how-it-is-being-launched

Answer (score 0):

Based on Feedback the Answer is that no main activity is required for an Android application.