# Android Can Applicaton Detect How it is being Launched?

Tags: android, android-activity, boot

Is there a way for Android application to detect how it is being launched?  whether by a BOOT or by user launching the application from the application list?

When my application is launched on boot I don't want any activity to show at all.  When the user specifically launches it from the application list,  then and only then would I want the main activity to show.  If I could detect whether the launch was a user launch or system boot launch I might be able to control this.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want two separate activities, one launched on boot and another launched explicitly. Actually, the one launched on boot maybe should be a Service instead.

Comment: I think this is close however now the question is really to understand all the circumstances under which MAIN action gets called.  So what your saying would work unless android calls main at other times beside launch?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Intent that started the application. In the manifest file of your Android project you can specify which Intents will launch which Activities. The documentation page for Intent actually has a really thorough explanation of how to use this feature, with example code and everything:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

The Intent that will be called when a user selects your application from a launcher will look like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you want a different Activity to launch when the phone boots (there's an intent filter value "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"), you just add a different IntentFilter to the Activity's tag in the manifest.

Comment: close.  I don't any Intent to fire when android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: the intent filter you posted does indeed run when the user launches the app, however I am finding that android will also use the main intent in other ways and at other times.  In other words android seems to use this whenever the application comes back into focus for some reason.  I want this activity to be run on launch only and afterwords and not reshow.  Perhaps this is a matter of having the activity close itself upon user interaction.  Do you know if this android.intent.action.MAIN fires at any other time?

Comment: any other time beside user launch?